# django NoReverseMatch error for related object when in a loop

Tags: django, django-urls

My model: a "Workshop" has a related item that stores time and place in a "Session" object:

```
item=models.OneToOneField(Session)
```

a Session stores the location as a foreign key to the locations:

```
location = models.ForeignKey(conference_models.Location,
        verbose_name=_("location"), blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm showing a Workshop in a template and I want to link to its location. If the template is a single Workshop view, this all works, but if I pass a list of workshops and wrap this all in:

```
{% for w in workshops %}
```

then bad things happen...

I have this in urls.py to define the URL for a location view:

```
url(r'^locations/(?P<location_pk>\d+)/$',
  views.view_location, name='view-location'),
```

and in the workshop template I have:

```
<a href="{% url 'view-location' location_pk=w.item.location.pk %}">
{{w.item.location.pk}} {{w.item.location}}</a> 
- {{w.item.start}} to {{w.item.end}}
```

And I get `Reverse for 'view-location' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'location_pk': ''}' not found.`

where `location_pk` is the parameter to my location view. Everything seems to be correct. For example, if I do:

```
   <a href="{% url 'view-location' location_pk=123546 %}">
    {{w.item.location.pk}} {{w.item.location}}</a> 
    - {{w.item.start}} to {{w.item.end}}
```

I get the expected URL with 123546 in it. If I do:

```
   <a href="{% url 'view-location' location_pk=w.item.pk %}">
    {{w.item.location.pk}} {{w.item.location}}</a> 
    - {{w.item.start}} to {{w.item.end}}
```

then I get the item primary key in the URL (which isn't what I want, but proves the point that I'm not going mad expecting this to work...).

In all cases the `{{w.item.location.pk}}` tag expands to the correct value.

I've tried wrapping it in a `{% with %}` tag so there's no dotting going on.  No joy.

This is Django 1.4.5, part of a complex project that probably won't handle an update to 1.5. If this requires 1.5 for a bigfix I'll have to rethink...

Note this only seems to happen in a `{% for %}` loop...

Comment: did you see in django shell if `w.item.location.pk` indeed returns a value, because from the error it looks like `w.item.location.pk` is evaluating to `''`

Comment: Yes its fine in the shell, and that's why I put it in `{{w.item.location.pk}}` in the template as well. Ah... except for one workshop which doesn't have a location set! I think you've got it. w.item.location is None for one of them, and the template dies...

Comment: Confirmed. Feel free to write an answer if you want the rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `location` field has `null=True, blank=True`, There might be some entries which are null, hence `w.item.location.pk` is evaluating to `''`.

You can check `{% if w.item.location %}` and then load the URL for location.

Comment: Jeff Croft has a nice blog post about the url tag gotchas: http://jeffcroft.com/blog/2008/nov/10/djangos-url-template-tag-sucks/